# How to enter newline character in Oracle?

Tags: oracle

```
select col1, col2
    into name1, name2
    from table1
    where col1=col;

        m_sub := 'Subject ';
    m_msg := 'Hello '||name||' ,'||/n||/n||'Your order has been placed.';
```

---

> Error(34,33): PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "/" when expecting one
>   of the following:     ( - + case mod new null       avg    count
>   current max min prior sql stddev sum variance execute    forall merge
>   time timestamp interval date          pipe

Comment: A newline is usually `\n`. I don't have an Oracle instance to play with right now but you should probably include it within the quotes, eg `'Hello '||name||' ,\n\nYour order has been placed.'`

Comment: I tried as you said, but when I execute my procedure, it prints:
Hello Brian, \n\nYour order has been placed.

Answer (score 159, accepted):

[Chr(Number)](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/olap.102/b14346/dml_x_chgdfn003.htm) should work for you.

```
select 'Hello' || chr(10) ||' world' from dual
```

Remember different platforms expect different new line characters:

- CHR(10) => LF, line feed (unix)
- CHR(13) => CR, carriage return (windows, together with LF)

Comment: Is there anyway to do this without returning quotes (") ? For example to return... Hello*linebreak* world__ ...instead of...  "Hello*linebreak* world"  ...?

Comment: The data does not contain quotes.   It is the tool you are using that is returning the quotes.

Comment: Using SQL Developer 4.1 to query. Then where ever I paste the results quotes are around that string.

Comment: Sounds like an great question new question to ask.   I don't use SQL Developer.

Answer (score 8):

According to the Oracle PLSQL language definition, a character literal can contain "any printable character in the character set". https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/02_funds.htm#2876

@Robert Love's answer exhibits a best practice for readable code, but you can also just type in the linefeed character into the code. Here is an example from a Linux terminal using `sqlplus`:

```
SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> begin   
  2  dbms_output.put_line( 'hello' || chr(10) || 'world' );
  3  end;
  4  /
hello
world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL> begin
  2  dbms_output.put_line( 'hello
  3  world' );
  4  end;
  5  /
hello
world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Instead of the CHR( NN ) function you can also use Unicode literal escape sequences like `u'\0085'` which I prefer because, well you know we are not living in 1970 anymore. See the equivalent example below:

```
SQL> begin
  2  dbms_output.put_line( 'hello' || u'\000A' || 'world' );
  3  end;
  4  /
hello
world

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

For fair coverage I guess it is worth noting that different operating systems use different characters/character sequences for end of line handling. You've got to have a think about the context in which your program output is going to be viewed or printed, in order to determine whether you are using the right technique.

- Microsoft Windows: CR/LF or `u'\000D\000A'`
- Unix (including Apple MacOS): LF or `u'\000A'`
- IBM OS390: NEL or `u'\0085'`
- HTML: `'<BR>'`
- XHTML: `'<br />'`
- etc. etc.

Comment: <br/> worked for me in an interactive report cell in an Oracle Apex app, for a case with list aggregation of column values. Great that you provided multiple answers, we should all do that

Answer (score 6):

```
begin   
   dbms_output.put_line( 'hello' ||chr(13) || chr(10) || 'world' );
end;
```