# How to add new line character in DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line in LINUX

Tags: sql, linux, oracle, unix, plsql

In UNIX, in a SQL script, i have following code:

```
LOOP    
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_key||'|'||p_loc||'\n');    
END LOOP
```

Output is:

```
5482004|Dir/3-30-2017/file:47923.xml

5482009|Dir/3-30-2017/file:49288.xml
```

However in Linux, since "\n" doesn't work, i am replacing the above code with following code:

```
LOOP    
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_key||'|'||p_loc);    
  DBMS_OUTPUT.new_line;    
END LOOP
```

Output is:

```
20 5482004|Dir/3-30-2017/file:447923.xml 5482009|Dir/3-30-2017/file:449288.xml 5482010|Dir/3-30-2017/file:449739.xml 5482012|Dir/3-30-2017/file:45015.xml
```

The output in this format is without the new line after each line. Please suggest what is in correct in the loop.

P.S. I have also tried `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_key||'|'||p_loc||chr(10))` but the output is still without the new line.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter newline character in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812148/how-to-enter-newline-character-in-oracle)

Answer (score 1):

Please refer below SO answer for this question.

**[New Line Character in dbms_output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812148/how-to-enter-newline-character-in-oracle)**

Comment: I did use DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_key||'|'||p_loc||chr(10)); but the output is still 5482004|Dir/3-30-2017/file:447923.xml 5482009|Dir/3-30-2017/file:449288.xml 5482010|Dir/3-30-2017/file:449739.xml 5482012|Dir/3-30-2017/file:45015.xml format and not in new line one

Comment: LOOP    
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line (p_key||'|'||p_loc);    
  DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line(chr(10));  
END LOOP

Comment: i tried the same, but didn't make any difference to the output format

Answer (score 1):

You can use **chr(10)**
My code in which i was trying to swap numbers ,where i need new line so i used chr(10)

```
DECLARE 
    A NUMBER;
    B NUMBER;
    TEMP NUMBER;
BEGIN
    A:=&A;
    B:=&B;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(chr(10)||'BEFORE SWAP A is : '||A||' AND B is : '||B);
    TEMP:=B;
    B:=A;
    A:=TEMP;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(' AFTER  SWAP A is : '||A||' AND B is : '||B);
END;
/
```

```
Output:

Enter value for a: 1
old   6:   A:=&A;
new   6:   A:=1;
Enter value for b: 2
old   7:   B:=&B;
new   7:   B:=2;
                                 -- here i got new line
BEFORE SWAP A is : 1 AND B is : 2
AFTER  SWAP A is : 2 AND B is : 1

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

**So before line(i.e BEFORE SWAP A is : 1 AND B is : 2) in output i got new line.**