# Link Break in SQL

Tags: line, break

What's the symbol or expression for a line break in oracle sql?
Ive searched everywhere without success, so that an expression 'line1line2' is written :

line
line2 (One beneath the other)

This is the code:

```
SELECT NVL2(TRIM(NAME),TRIM(NAME),NULL)||CHR(13)|| NVL2(TRIM(STATE),TRIM(STATE),NULL)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enter newline character in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812148/how-to-enter-newline-character-in-oracle)

Comment: Im still unable to get a new line . This is the code:    SELECT NVL2(TRIM(NAME),TRIM(NAME),NULL)||CHR(13)||
NVL2(TRIM(ADR),TRIM(ADR),NULL) from table a

Comment: have you tried adding `chr(10)` as well, so you get CR+LF instead of just CR?

Comment: That doesnt work! ||chr(13) ||chr(10)|| doesnt work