# Oracle - How to find carriage return, new line and tab using REGEXP_LIKE?

Tags: regex, oracle, regexp-like

I am trying to run a query in Oracle 11g where I am looking in a VARCHAR column for any rows that contain any of a carriage return, new line or tab. So far my code is as shown

```
select c1 from table_name where regexp_like(c1, '[\r\n\t]')
```

Not sure why but I am getting unexpected results. I saw some mention that Oracle doesnt support '\r' or any of the other characters I used? Some folks mentioned to use chr(10) for example and then I tried the following code

```
select c1 from table_name where regexp_like(c1, '[chr(10)|chr(13)]')
```

And again I am getting unexpected results. Pretty sure I am misunderstanding something here and I was hoping for some guidance.

Comment: Is your aim to remove them? Btw, where do you need, within such as SQL loader ..?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to enter newline character in Oracle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5812148/how-to-enter-newline-character-in-oracle)

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan - Eventually I may want to remove them but for now I would settle for just finding them. I think I may have my answer below though

Comment: @Nick - Not exactly but it does help further support that I need to use the chr() function. Just not quite clear why though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```sql
select c1
from   table_name
where  c1 LIKE '%' || chr(10) || '%'
or     c1 LIKE '%' || chr(13) || '%'
or     c1 LIKE '%' || chr(9) || '%';
```

or

```sql
select c1
from   table_name
where  regexp_like(c1, '[' || chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(9) || ']')
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/JcYiHcf6)

---

`where regexp_like(c1, '[\r\n\t]')` does not work as you are matching any character that is `\` or `r` or `\` or `n` or `\` or `t` (and not matching the perl-like character sets `\r`, `\n` or `\t`).

`where regexp_like(c1, '[chr(10)|chr(13)]')` does not wotk as you are matching any character that is `c` or `h` or `r` or `(` or `1` or `0` or `)` or `|` or `c` or `h` or `r` or `(` or `1` or `3` or `)` as you have a string literal and are not evaluating the contents of the literal. If you want to evaluate them as calls to the `CHR` function then it must be outside the string literal as the second example above.

Comment: This totally helped clarify what I was looking for! I was totally confused on why even use the chr() function, and secondly I was getting lost in other peoples examples and no one broke down the problem like you did! I further improved on this code and added a '|' pipe delimiter between chr(10) etc as an explicit "or" - but this did the trick! Thank you!

Comment: @rodneyc8063 If you are using it as `'[' || chr(10) || '|' || chr(13) || '|' || chr(9) || ']'` then that is wrong and you do not want the pipe character as does not act as an `OR` operator but instead would be matched as a character within the character set.

Comment: Ugh that was exactly what I tried and it "seemed" to work (at least it didnt error). I did some reading and if I got it right the `[]` acts as an implicit `OR` already and I dont need the `|` delimiter it seems. Would that mean I could either use `'[' || chr(10) || chr(13) || chr(9) || ']'` or could I also use `chr(10) || '|' || chr(13) || '|' || chr(9)` ? I am guessing if I got it straight these two statements are equivalent?

Comment: @rodneyc8063 Yes (although you might want round brackets around the second option if you are also matching anything before or after it)